# Add path to zend view in plugin

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to add a new path to my view scripts in a preDispatch plugin.

My ultimate goal is to run several sites from the same Zend Framework application each with their own layout and view scripts.  However I wish to use the default layout/views where a site does not have its own view/layout.

I have got the layout to work correctly but I cannot get the view scripts to load.

My views folder layout is as follows

```
/application
    /modules
        /views
            /scripts
                /index
                    index.phtml -> the default index controller view script
                /sites
                    /domingod -> this is a site
                        /index
                            /index.phtml -> the sites index controller view script
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the index view script in domingod/index/index.phtml to be loaded, if this file is not found the I want the default index.phtml view script to render.

I have tried this so far but with no luck

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->getView()->setScriptPath($viewScriptPath);
```

This seems to add the path but ZF is still rendering the default index.phtml rather than the sites (domingod) one.

I hope this all makes sense, many thanks in advance.

Garry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to check if the site had a view script, if it had then set that to render.

```
class FreedomS_Zend_Controller_Plugin_SetView extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
        {
            $module = $request->getModuleName();
            $controller = $request->getControllerName();
            $action = $request->getActionName();

            $viewScriptPath = APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/' . $module . '/views/scripts/sites/' . Zend_Registry::get('siteId') . '/';

            $view = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->view;
            if (file_exists($viewScriptPath . $controller . '/' . $action . '.phtml'))
                $view->addScriptPath($viewScriptPath);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it always looks for index/index.phtml. This is base action and base controller. If you want to achive your goal, I think you should set redirection there with some checking.

```
$this->_redirect(   $this
                            ->view
                            ->url(array('controller' => 'domingod',
                                        'action' => 'index')));
            return;
```

But in my humble opinion, you should know for sure what you have on your site and what you dont. If site doesn't have to exist, set there a redirection link, and your web site would work as a swiss clock.

Comment: Hi JohnyPHP thanks for your answer.  I don't need separate controllers for each site as they all function the same.  I can use my plugin to determine which view script to render if necessary but how do I change the view script to render in a plugin?

Comment: $this->_helper->viewRenderer('index/index', null, true);
This is the way view is rendered from a controller. Thought never did it using plugin...

Comment: JohnyPHP: can you imadine that case if you wouldn't add this $this->_helper->viewRenderer('index/index', null, true); line to all of your controllers? Garry was right.